# How to find out which XAML file causes data binding error?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's the "super friendly" error message I get:

> Cannot convert '' from type '' to type
>   'System.Windows.Thickness' for 'en-US' culture with default
>   conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.
>   NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException:
>   ThicknessConverter cannot convert from (null).    at
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object
>   value)    at
>   System.Windows.ThicknessConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   typeDescriptorContext, CultureInfo cultureInfo, Object source)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type
>   destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean isForward)'

I have dozens of huge XAML files in my app. Dozens of data bindings.
The app itself is multi-threaded, so some synchronization is used when non-GUI threads access the GUI.

When my explicitly written C# code misbehave - I get an exception and a stack trace. 1 minute later it's fixed. But when a bug in my code causes XAML generated code to misbehave - I'm here. Completely clueless.

Comment: This does not look like thread issue. More like incompatible type. Check bindings to `Margin`, `Padding` or `BorderThickness` where source property is not `Thickness` (maybe `string`) and value is `null`

Comment: OK, I found it. But it was a wild guess. I just checked recently added bindings and I found one which should be removed, because it referenced removed element. But anyway, is there a way to do it without guessing?

Comment: There is [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) tool which can show you objects with binding errors. Caveat here is that the app must start first

Comment: If it only wasn't abandoned for years... For now I think the best way to avoid data binding errors is to test each binding immediately. Also each code change which can affect the binding should be tested immediately. Then, debug / console output has some clues. Except this error message I pasted, I found another one in console. It was easy to miss among many similar, but it had source property name, that rang the bell. Still guessing, but much easier to guess. BTW, in case of data binding errors app mostly starts normally, the UI malfunctions though. In my case it worked but lagged.